# Visual Studio Code - HTML IntelliSence Attribute

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been looking around but haven't found really an answer.
Some attributes do have a value or path and other don't.

Attribute with a value:
[image: Attribute with a value]

Attribute without a value that isn't relevant:
[image: Attribute without a value that isn't relevant]

It does show some values but not relevant to the attribute.

Is there some sort of setting or extension in Visual Studio Code for this.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but the fields that "don't have a relevant value" just get suggestions from your document. Those fields could be anything and it has no other data to guess from.

Comment: What I mean is like in brackets. For the link - rel attribute it can show the values of the rel attribute.
Was wondering if Visual Studio Code could do the same.